# Laravel Charts Refresh With Ajax

Tags: laravel, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to implement a chart in a webpage (laravel) using laravel charts liberary.
Current I was able to populate the data using

```
{!! $chart->container() !!}
```

in the view.

I want to write a js function to refresh the chart data every minute.

In laravel charts documentation they have provided a code like the following, so it'll return the values we need to the view.

```
chart = new SampleChart;
$chart->dataset('Sample Test', 'bar', [3,4,1]);
$chart->dataset('Sample Test', 'line', [1,4,3]);
return $chart->api();
```

js

```
var original_api_url = {{ $chart->id }}_api_url;
{{ $chart->id }}_refresh(original_api_url);
```

What I don't underatand is, where to use tese functions and how to use these refresh function to refresh my chart ?
Aprt from that, do we have to replace the _api_url part of the  {{ $chart->id }}_api_url; of the above mentioned js ?

I'm new to laravel. If you are familiar in using laravel charts, please let me know how to solve this.

Documentation url
https://charts.erik.cat/api_charts.html#building-the-chart

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to use the refresh functionality you need a controller with a method to return the data as json.

So create a new controller method:

```php
public function chartApi() {
    $chart = new SampleChart;
    $chart->dataset('Sample Test', 'bar', [3,4,1]);
    $chart->dataset('Sample Test', 'line', [1,4,3]);
    return $chart->api();
}
```

And add a route for it:

```php
Route::get('chart-data', ['uses' => 'YourController@chartApi']);
```

Then, in your controller that is rendering the chart view:

```php
$chart = new SampleChart;

$api = url('/chart-data');

$chart->labels(['test1', 'test2', 'test3'])->load($api)

return view('yourview', ['chart' => $chart]);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much
Just need to clarify one more thing.

in 
    var original_api_url = {{ $chart->id }}_api_url;
    {{ $chart->id }}_refresh(original_api_url);

those files, do we have to replace the values of _api_url? 
currently, it gives an error saying it's not defined.

Comment: I haven't used the load function. That was the issue.
It got fixed. That you verymuch.